# Uk visa application form filling doubt

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am going to travel alone to the UK for holidays and am a student. My sponsors are my FATHER and my COUSIN. I have a doubt regarding what option in the application form to select for this question:

*Who will pay towards your trip?*

And there is only one option to be selected. My FATHER will be buying air tickets and take responsibility of all expenses till I reach UK and My COUSIN will pay for everything while I am in the UK.

So what option should I select: Father or Cousin?

Comment: The one with the senior immigration status in the UK gets listed in the "Employment and Income" section and all the others get listed in "Additional Information"

Comment: What does senior immigration status in the UK means?

Comment: The one who is a citizen, or closest to citizenship.

Comment: As my cousin is in UK.The answer is cousin.              Thank you Gayot fow